# How to evaluate the distance between two linear spaces in python (numpy/scipy etc)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, distance

I would like to evaluate the distance between two liner spaces. In fact, i would like to try several metric distances for example, as listed in http://meeting.xidian.edu.cn/workshop/miis2014/uploads/files/July-9th-1100am_Lek-Heng%20Lim_distance%20between%20subspaces%20of%20different%20dimensions.pdf

(slide 12, the definition of angles is made at slide 8)

It seems i have to solve an optimization problem as a preliminary step.
Is there any existed pakage to do it in python?

Comment: Your question needs to be self contained; most of us won't bother to look at an external source, much less digest it for you.  The ideal is described in [mcve].

Comment: scipy has optimization methods, as well spatial code.  Also look at sklearn.